# How to add source code comments in Thymeleaf templates that don't get included in generated HTML?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using full stack Thymeleaf (spring mvc, security, layout dialect, webflow) in a mid-size web application.

Ok..now that we put so much of code in the html templates it would be nice to include source code comments that don't get included in the generated HTML file.

How do we achieve that?

Comment: For what is worth, the Thymeleaf page has it's own forum for support. That's why I removed the first part of your message and why this question might get more attention there.

Answer (score 87):

Version 2.1 is released so now you can upgrade your libraries and use comments in your code. With this version developers are able to use parser-level comment blocks:

```
<!--/* This code will be removed at thymeleaf parsing time! */-->
```

and prototype-only comment blocks:

```
<span>hello!</span>
<!--/*/
    <div th:text="${...}">

</div>
/*/-->
<span>goodbye!</span>
```

Detailed explanation can be found in the official documentation here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#comments-and-blocks

Comment: Note that <!--/* should be written with no space between <!-- and /*. Just thought to mention it since I got bitten by it.

Comment: thymeleaf 3.0.11, no effect by me.

Comment: comment block should look like `<!--/*--> your multi-line comment <!--*/-->`

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned [Rafal Borowiec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718515/rafal-borowiec) to comment block of HTML code you should use

`<!--/*`something to comment`*/-->` construction (see [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#thymeleaf-parser-level-comment-blocks)).

Also it is possible to comment/remove your javascript code using thymeleaf with

`/*[-` something to comment `-]*/` construction (see [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#removing-code)). So you can annotate your js code without leaking any information

```
/*[-
 *
 * Some information about function.
 *
 * -]*/
function someFunction() {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

Comment: regarding the JS code commenting you have to put `th:inline="javascript"` to your script tag like this: `<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">`, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 12):

With Thymeleaf 3.0, the currently working version was

```
<!--/*-->
   this comment will be removed by thymeleaf on the template processing
<!--*/-->
```

Other answers, for earlier thymeleaf versions, did not work by me. The current thymeleaf documentation is [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#comments-and-blocks).

Answer (score 4):

Prior to version 2.1 you can do this

```
<th:block th:if="${false}"><!--   ignore me  --></th:block>
```

Its very ugly (the `th:block` needing a false `th:if`) but works.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in current stable version of Thymeleaf. It's planned for version 2.1 as mentioned in [Thymeleaf Issue 10](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/10)